# bootstrap grid different column height and width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to achieve this on bootstrap: 
http://s2.postimg.org/nrbrjp4xl/layout.png
Last two columns stay with a distance, I want them all stacked. how can I fix this?

here is a sample of my code on JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alamshahi/9bbw0aL1/)

and here is the code:

```css
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Static navbar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/30/30/arch/grayscale"> </a> </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a></li>
        <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></a></li>
        <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse --> 
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid full-height">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 --> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 --> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <!-- /col-md-3 --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /row --> 
</div>
<!-- /container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bbw0aL1/2/

I spotted a few typos in your code, where you had

```
col-md-3 col-sm-6
```

Maybe it was your goal, but I suppose that the fiddle's window is small enought to render the images according to the col-sm-value. That helped in the first row.

In the second row you need to use e.g. nested columns (more info here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/30/30/arch/grayscale"> </a> 
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Culture</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stories</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                </li>
                <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="no-dash"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid full-height">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 feature-item"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/640/arch/grayscale" alt=""> </a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
</div>
<!-- /container-fluid -->
```